# How can I pause the main thread while TimerTask is executing?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package demo;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Demo {
    public static Timer timer = new Timer();

    static {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin..."); 

        while (true) {
            // do something         
        }
    }

}

class MyTask extends TimerTask { 
    public void run() {
        // do something 

        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        Demo.timer.schedule(task, 1000);
    }
}
```

How can I make the `main` thread paused while the `TimerTask` is entered and resumed when it exits.

Comment: Implying 1*1000 is anything other than 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lock and wait until MyTask sets isFinished flag and calls lock.notify()

```
static Object lock = new Object();
static boolean isFinished;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Begin...");
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (!isFinished) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

note that lock.wait() needs to be in a while loop, Java does not guarantee that your thread will be woken up only by a notify, see Object.wait API

Answer (score 0):

The usefulness sort of depends on how long the 'do something' in your main loop takes to execute, if it's a long time your timer tasks will have an unpredictable interval, because they need to wait for the current pass of the loop to complete.  The main thread pauses to let the timer task have the lock at the end of the loop, and won't resume again until the timer task is done and releases the lock.  Passing 'true' to the constructor makes the lock 'fair' so that it ensures timertask gets a chance to run and the main loop doesn't keep just retaking the lock indefinitely.

Also, see this article on why the timer task cannot (well, should not, you can still actually do it...) order the main thread ti just stop arbitrarily:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

```
package demo;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Demo {
    public static Timer timer = new Timer();
    public static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    static {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        timer.schedule(task, 1000);     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Begin..."); 

        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
            // do something
            finally {
              lock.unlock();
            }         
        }
    }

}

class MyTask extends TimerTask { 
    public void run() {
        Demo.lock.lock();
        try {
          // do something

          MyTask task = new MyTask();
          Demo.timer.schedule(task, 1000);
        finally {
            Demo.lock.unlock();
        } 
    }
}
```